# How should I proceed in troubleshooting rtorrent?

Tags: rtorrent

I have a computer connected via ethernet cables to my home router that preforms server like duties. Specifically, for some time I was running rtorrent on this machine. I wish I knew when this started to occur (then I could try and associate the break with an event), yet mysteriously all of my active torrents suddenly failed to seed or download. The program error message read `Tracker: [Failed sending data to the peer]`.

My first attempt at troubleshooting was to completely uninstall and reinstall rtorrent. I rewrote (read: uncommented the example) my config files and started clean. The first torrent file in erred with the same message. I am familiar with the common key sequences to fix torrents that go rogue in rtorrent: `C-d, C-k, C-e, C-r, C-s` and many variations on the same, none of them proved fruitful.

Next up the operating system. I formatted a rather poorly maintained Linux Mint install and wrote it over with a fresh command-line Ubuntu installation. Feeling sure that I had nuked the issue I installed rtorrent only to once again be greeted with `[Failed sending data to the peer]`.

If my thinking is logical the next step would be to investigate the connection between the machine and the router. However I am not really sure how to do that (only an amateur with network engineering) or what to analyze/check or even how to start. Any recommendations for how to proceed? Also if you need any specifics about the setup to offer advice, just ask and I will post links to config files or other information.

Extra Info: I can successfully download torrents from other machines on the same subnet.

**Edit 1**: I've verified something suspicious about the machine in question. When it is requested to `ping www.google.com` it replies `unknown host` If I discover google's public IP on a different computer (same subnet!) and then using that information request the faulty machine to `ping 74.125.239.131` instead it succeeds. Could this DNS issue (that's what it is right?) be affecting the torrent protocol?

Comment: Have you established that your ISP isn't blocking P2P traffic? Have you tried changing ports?

Comment: I have tried changing ports, initially I was using a block in the 6000 range, now I'm in the 50000s. I am currently running the ISP P2P test, but I think that it is unlikely to be the case. I believe this because I can torrent from other machines on the same subnet.

Comment: I'd try a different client just to confirm whether it's the setup of the computer itself or rtorrent. I use [vuze](http://www.vuze.com/), works well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jasonwryan, sounds like your ISP is potentially blocking you. You can use this online test to confirm if this is in fact the case. The service is called [BitTorrent Test](http://www.bittorrenttest.com/).

**NOTE**: This test requires that you have Java enabled as a plugin in your browser.

#### Screenshot of results page

Here's what the results page looks like after performing a test. A test includes both a download and upload.

[image: ss of results page]

Comment: The BitTorrent Test reported that my ISP does not limit my torrent bandwidth. How I wish this were the case: I'm sure it's just something stupid that I have overlooked.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for testing BitTorrent from the command line? My rtorrent box only has a terminal.

Comment: Check out this EFF article: http://www.eff.org/wp/detecting-packet-injection, might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so apparently the issue comes down to be setting up my static IP address incorrectly for this computer. I had not prescribed a DNS server properly, and upon switching it back to dhcp my torrent client regained functionality.

I guess at this point if I have any more issues with this they could be focused at ubuntu.stackexchange. Thanks slm and jasonwryan for your assistance.